# Glassfish 4.1 on OpenJDK 8? (Netbeans)

Tags: software-installation, java, webserver, database, development

Netbeans installed Glassfish, and shows Glassfish as running:

```
Running the create-domain subcommand
Using default port 4848 for Admin.
Using default port 8080 for HTTP Instance.
Using default port 7676 for JMS.
Using default port 3700 for IIOP.
Using default port 8181 for HTTP_SSL.
Using default port 3820 for IIOP_SSL.
Using default port 3920 for IIOP_MUTUALAUTH.
Using default port 8686 for JMX_ADMIN.
Using default port 6666 for OSGI_SHELL.
Using default port 9009 for JAVA_DEBUGGER.
Distinguished Name of the self-signed X.509 Server Certificate is:
[CN=dur.bounceme.net,OU=GlassFish,O=Oracle Corporation,L=Santa Clara,ST=California,C=US]
Distinguished Name of the self-signed X.509 Server Certificate is:
[CN=dur.bounceme.net-instance,OU=GlassFish,O=Oracle Corporation,L=Santa Clara,ST=California,C=US]
Domain dur created.
Domain dur admin port is 4848.
Domain dur allows admin login as user "anonymous" with no password.
Command create-domain executed successfully.
```

Sure enough, browsing to the admin port, 4848 on local host as by default, brings up the GUI well enough.  But, how do I access `asadmin` from the CLI?

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ GlassFish_Server/bin/asadmin list-domains
GlassFish requires Java SE version 6.  Your JDK is version 0
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/javac          1091      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1081      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/javac          1091      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ head GlassFish_Server/README.txt 
Thank you for downloading GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1!

Here are a few short steps to get you started...


0. Prerequisite
===============

GlassFish 4.1 requires Oracle JDK 7 Update 65+ or Oracle JDK 8 Update 5+. 
Check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html to download the JDK.
thufir@dur:~$
```

Which is inconsistent on several levels.  Do I have to go and install **Oracle** JDK 8 just to run Glassfish 4.x??

see also:

https://serverfault.com/q/779692/

Comment: That " Your JDK version is 0" is your hint.  Do you only have a JRE installed, or do you have a JDK installed?  How did you install it?  Is the JAVA_HOME environment variable set?  If so, what does it point to?

Comment: doesn't `javac -version` indicate that I'm using `JDK`?

Answer (score 1):

Switching to Oracle JDK 8:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sdk ls java

================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
     9.0.1-oracle                                                                  
 > * 9.0.0-zulu                                                                    
     8u151-oracle                                                                  
     8u144-zulu                                                                    
     8u131-zulu                                                                    
     7u141-zulu                                                                    
     6u93-zulu                                                                     









================================================================================
+ - local version
* - installed
> - currently in use
================================================================================
thufir@dur:~$ sdk install java 8u151-oracle

Oracle requires that you agree with the Oracle Binary Code License Agreement
prior to installation. The license agreement can be found at:

  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html

Do you agree to the terms of this agreement? (Y/n): Y


Downloading: java 8u151-oracle

In progress...

######################################################################## 100.0%

Repackaging Java 8u151-oracle...

Done repackaging...

Installing: java 8u151-oracle
Done installing!

Do you want java 8u151-oracle to be set as default? (Y/n): Y

Setting java 8u151-oracle as default.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_151
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
[sudo] password for thufir: 
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ GlassFish_Server/
bin/                  javadb/               .org.opensolaris,pkg/ 
glassfish/            mq/                   pkg/                  
thufir@dur:~$ GlassFish_Server/bin/
asadmin     pkg         updatetool  
thufir@dur:~$ GlassFish_Server/bin/asadmin list-domains
domain1 not running
dur2 not running
dur not running
Command list-domains executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$
```

works fine.